# Take specific number of array first then process

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this code below that:

```
InstanceCollection instances = this.MyService(typeID, referencesIDs);
```

My problem here is when the `referencesIDs.Count()` is greater than a specific count, it throws an error which is related to `SQL`.

Suggested to me is to call the `this.MyService` multiple times so it won't process many `referencesIDs`.

What is the way to do that? I am thinking of using a while loop like this:

```
while (referencesIDs.Count() != maxCount)
{
    newReferencesIDs = referencesIDs.Take(500).ToArray();
    instances = this.MyService(typeID, newReferencesIDs);
    maxCount += newReferencesIDs.Count();
}
```

The problem that I can see here is that how can I remove the first 500 referencesIDs on the newReferencesIDs? Because if I won't remove the first 500 after the first loop, it will continue to add the referencesIDs.

Comment: Use `Skip()`, so `newReferenceIDs = referenceIDs.Skip(500).Take(500).ToArray()`

Comment: Obviously, next time you need `Skip(2 * 500)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking to update the `referencesIDs` value?  Something like this?:

```
referencesIDs = referencesIDs.Skip(500);
```

Then the next time you call `.Take(500)` on `referencesIDs` it'll get the *next* 500 values.

Conversely, without updating the `referencesIDs` variable, you can include the `Skip` in your loop.  Something like this:

```
var pageSize = 500;
var skipCount = 0;
while(...)
{
    newReferencesIDs = referencesIDs.Skip(skipCount).Take(pageSize).ToArray();
    skipCount += pageSize;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Was just about to suggest a `pageSize` variable!

Answer (score 2):

My first choice would be to fix the service, if you have access to it. A SQL-specific error could be a result of an incomplete database configuration, or a poorly written SQL query on the server. For example, Oracle limits `IN` lists in SQL queries to about 1000 items by default, but your Oracle DBA should be able to re-configure this limit for you. Alternatively, server side programmers could rewrite their query to avoid hitting this limit in the first place.

If this does not work, you could split your list into blocks of max size that does not trigger the error, make multiple calls to the server, and combine the instances on your end, like this:

```
InstanceCollection instances = referencesIDs
    .Select((id, index) => new {Id = id, Index = index})
    .GroupBy(p => p.Index / 500) // 500 is the max number of IDs
    .SelectMany(g => this.MyService(typeID, g.Select(item => item.Id).ToArray()))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: +1, one difference might be that this will change the order of IDs in case they weren't sorted (which may or may not matter to OP).

Comment: Thank you for this. I know modifying the SQL is much better but I have SLA to meet. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general way of splitting lists into chunks, you can use something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Split a source IEnumerable into smaller (more manageable) lists.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<IList<TSource>> 
    SplitIntoChunks<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int chunkSize)
{
    long i = 1;
    var list = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (var t in source)
    {
        list.Add(t);
        if (i++ % chunkSize == 0)
        {
            yield return list;
            list = new List<TSource>();
        }
    }
    if (list.Count > 0)
        yield return list;
}
```

And then you can use `SelectMany` to flatten results:

```
InstanceCollection instances = referencesIDs
    .SplitIntoChunks(500)
    .SelectMany(chunk => MyService(typeID, chunk))
    .ToList();
```